# How to handle right mouse click event for QGraphicsItem?

Tags: qt, events, click, mouse

I have a class derived from QGraphicsItem, which is basically like this:

```
class MyRect: public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
{     
        Q_OBJECT
        Q_INTERFACES(QGraphicsItem)
public:
        explicit MyRect(QObject *parent = 0);
        MyRect(QColor fillColor, float val, QString txt = "", bool isLeaf = false);
        int width, height;  
protected:
        virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
        virtual void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);          
        virtual QRectF boundingRect() const;
        virtual void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
};
```

The problem is the mouseReleaseEvent and mousePressEvent only accept QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent argument which cannot detect right button click. I know there is a mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) version that I can use, but it seems not work for QGraphicsItem....Just cannot get stuck here...I appreciate your answer.

Comment: seems you are not setting `setMouseTracking(true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-implementing [QGraphicsItem::contextMenuEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicsitem.html#contextMenuEvent) and checking the QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent::Reason for if the event was caused by a mouse click.

Comment: Thanks fjcarnevale. I will make a try for this. To solve this problem, I captured the right-mouse click event in the MainWindow, which I think might be the only solution...